# MYSQL CSV column check for exclude

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, sql-like

I need to find a record who dont have a specific value in CSV column. below is the table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `keywords` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Sample record1:  100, Sam, Thompson, "50,51,52,53"
Sample record2:  100, Wan, Thompson, "50,52,53"
Sample record3:  100, Kan, Thompson, "53,52,50"

50 = sports
51 = cricket
52 = soccer
53 = baseball
```

i need to find the employees name who has the tags of **"sports,soccer,baseball"** excluding cricket
so the result should return only 2nd and 3rd record in this example as they dont have 51(cricket) but all other 3 though in diff pattern.

My query is below, but i couldnt get it worked any more.

```
SELECT t.first_name,FROM `User` `t` WHERE (keywords like '50,52,53') LIMIT 10
```

is there anything like unlike option? i am confused how to get this worked.

Comment: Don't store data as comma separated items! It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `FIND_IN_SET`:

```
SELECT t.first_name
FROM `User` `t` 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('50', `keywords`) > 0
  AND FIND_IN_SET('52', `keywords`) > 0
  AND FIND_IN_SET('53', `keywords`) > 0
  AND FIND_IN_SET('51', `keywords`) = 0;
```

Keep in mind it could be slow. The correct way is to normalize your table structure.

Answer (score 1):

[FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) will do the job for you but **it does not use indexes**. This is not a bug it's a [feature](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=37564).

[SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) can use an index and return the data as you wish. You don't have an index on it at the moment, But the catch here is that [TEXT fields cannot be fully indexed](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/column-indexes.html) and what you have is a TEXT field.

**Normalize**!

This is what you really should be doing. It's not a good idea to store comma separated values in a database. You really should be having a keywords table and since the keywords will be short, you can have a char or varchar narrow column which can be fully indexed.